# Linkedin Authentication new code every time - python

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to access linkedin with Python. Below is the simple code I am using.

Problems is I need to login open browser every time to post the return_url for getting the authorization_code, it works for the first time when I run and this code expires when I re-run the python code.

Below is my code:

```
from linkedin import linkedin
API_KEY = '<mykey>'
API_SECRET = '<mysecret>'
RETURN_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize'
authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
Url= authentication.authorization_url  # open this url on your browser
print Url
authentication.authorization_code ="<authcode>"
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
authentication.get_access_token()
```

Comment: I notice that the API comes in 4 flavors (Sign In, Share, etc.). Which one are you using?

Comment: I dont know anything about that, I am a newbie :).. Any guidance please?

Comment: Please go to https://developer.linkedin.com/ and let me know which one of the four API 'facets' you selected or, if you have not seen this page before how did you sign up to use LinkedIn's API and get information about how to program using it?

Comment: I went to linkedin developers, there i see "My Apps" Tab. pressed "Create An Application" Provided details and I received Client ID and Client Secret. That is it.

Comment: I tried that but it requires questions that I cannot answer.  However, your question is tagged with 'linkedin' so someone from LinkedIn may respond since SO has been their support site since last December per https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/53170/~/linkedin-api-support-moves-to-stackoverflow, except the issue may be with the Python interface to their API which is not necessarily supported by them, namely python-linkedin isn't developed by a LinkedIn employee, but you can send an email to Ozgur Vatansever, its developer, directly at ozgurvt@gmail.com.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies. I will talk to Ozgur directly.